# Why is my object not filled up aspdotnet json converters

Tags: asp.net, json, json.net, jsonconvert, jsonconverter

I have a simple http server. I send some json object over POST

At first, I use json converter to parse the json and fill nonserializable objects up

```
public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    list<SomeClass> list = JArray.Load(reader).Cast<JObject>().Select(o => new SomeClass((string)o.GetValue("val1"), (string)o.GetValue("val2"))).ToList();
    return list;
}
```

The list is loaded fine, but on the next step the field of the class MyClass containing that list is empty

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult PostData([FromBody]MyClass myClass)
```

Where to look to fix this issue?

Comment: Next step would be to see the actual payload. E.g. install fiddler and then when you run the test see what is in the Request Body is in the fiddler trace.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle the json payload is okay since I get  the right data in the list. Also I used Firefox development tools and there was a pretty json object.

Comment: Ok, if you then add to question how MyClass looks like, and also the Json Body in the call. And then if you explain how MyClass and SomeClass is connected. (Unless someone else understand question better)

Comment: You sure your json object that you created is myClass? (Make sure your JSON object matches with the parameter variable in controller)

Comment: For some reason, my services tried to validate the class

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to look on the exception thrown and I could find the reason - validation of object. Solution:

```
services.AddMvc(options => options.ModelMetadataDetailsProviders.Add(new Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.SuppressChildValidationMetadataProvider(typeof(MyClass))))
```